# Query custom field from managed package object

Tags: trigger, soql, managed-package, chargent

```
[Select ChargentOrders__Amount__c from ChargentOrders__Transaction__c 
                                where ChargentOrders__Gateway_Date__c>:enrolldate and 
                                 ChargentOrders__Gateway_Date__c<:Yearlydate and ChargentOrders__Account__c=ChargentOrders.policy__c];
```

I have a requirement where i need to query a lookup custom field from managed package object.Here `ChargentOrders__Account__c` is the managed field and i am comparing that field with lookup custom field which i created`(Policy__c)`.
so for that i am using its namespace prefix and querying it.But it is throwing some syntax error.Is the syntax correct what i am using in where clause.

Comment: You can't filter between two fields like this: `ChargentOrders__Account__c=ChargentOrders.policy__c`. You should add a formula of type checkbox which is equals to `ChargentOrders__Account__c=ChargentOrders.policy__c`. Then you replace the end of your query with: `Your_New_Formula__c = true`

Comment: And even if you could your field would just be Policy__c. You don't add a namespace for local fields (also it would be __ not . If you needed to add) Also in the future always post the error message verbatim as it will help us help you